# WebDB / SQLite - Order By with Ignore Case?

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

Im bringing back my users and making a LISTVIEW .. but last name adams comes after Zen...

How can I get them to come back regardless of case?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do it per se, but what you can do is order by all upper (or lower) case:

```
SELECT Name
FROM People
ORDER BY upper(Name);
```